# Can't boot Ubuntu 19.04 or Ubuntu19.04 LiveUSB after enrolling MOK

Tags: ubuntu, boot, uefi, boot-loader, secure-boot

(I've asked this question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144041/cant-boot-ubuntu-or-ubuntu-usb-installation-after-enrolling-mok) with no response after 4 days.)

Before showing GRUB, it shows

> Unable to trigger tcg2 final events table: Invalid Parameter 
>   Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed 
>   : Invalid Parameter

and machine power off.

It's my first time to install Ubuntu 19.04 on this machine, DELL [T5810](https://www.dell.com/gy/business/p/precision-t5810-workstation/pd) with UEFI. The Ubuntu installation was fine, enrolling the [Machine Owner Key](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS) [MOK](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) caused the boot error. When I ran `sudo apt install virtualbox`. virtualbox installation prompted me to enroll MOK; I rebooted the machine, and enrolled MOK. Then it entered the above dead state.

**Booting from Ubuntu's LiveUSB installer shows the same error message.** Luckily, I can still boot into Windows 10 on the same machine. I just want to revert enrolling MOK. Not installing Virtualbox in future is acceptable.

What I've tried:

1. Searching the error message leads to mokutil, but I can't boot into a linux now.
2. I also tried reset BIOS, but it doesn't work at all (I have to repair windows boot).
3. Open EFI partition in Windows, deleted EFI/ubuntu, EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi, EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi.